# Se bloquea el scroll de la pantalla

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap, jquery-mobile

Tengo un problema que no sé cómo solucionar. He hecho una App con [html](/questions/tagged/html), [css](/questions/tagged/css), [php](/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) y [jquery-mobile](/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile). En mi móvil funciona correctamente pero hay en otros, incluso con la misma versión de Android que no pasa lo mismo. Cuando meto datos en un formulario bloquean el scroll de la pantalla no pudiendo acceder a los campos inferiores.

He puesto `style="overflow: scroll"` en cada `data-role="page"` pero se sigue bloqueando.

¿A qué puede ser debido? ¿Por qué en unos pasa y en otros no?

Necesito ayuda urgente.
Un saludo y gracias por vuestras respuestas que nos ayudan mucho a todos.

Comment: @sioesi Muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta. Pruebo y te digo algo. Un saludo desde España

Answer (score 1):

Esto ocurre porque aparentemente agregas campos al formulario después de que la pagina cargue completamente. Por lo tanto debes hacer un `resize`

Puedes verificar asi :

```
height = $(window).height();
```

Cuando agregues datos a tu formulario ya cargado

```
if($(window).height() != height){

}
```

Aquí verificar si el actual alto de tu pantalla es diferente al anterior, si es asi deberias actualizar el height

Otra manera que se me ocurre es agregar este css a tu clase contenedora del formulario.

```
height:100%; overflow:auto;
```